# Jest + React + TypeScript: default configuration

Tags: reactjs, typescript, configuration, jestjs

Can somebody provide a default 'working like a charm ;)' configuration example for a Jest + React + TypeScript app please?

Our current jest.config.js is

```
module.exports = {
roots: [ '/src' ],
transform: {
'^.+\.tsx?$': 'ts-jest',
'.+\.(css|styl|less|sass|scss|png|jpg|ttf|woff|woff2)$': 'jest-transform-stub',
},
testRegex: '(/tests/.*|(\.|/)(test|spec))\.tsx?$',
moduleFileExtensions: ['ts', 'tsx', 'js', 'jsx', 'json', 'node'],

// Setup Enzyme
snapshotSerializers: ['enzyme-to-json/serializer'],
setupFilesAfterEnv: ["/enzymeConfig.ts"]
}
```

It seems we are still missing something important but don't know what exactly..

Comment: What's the error that you're getting?

Comment: Usually I can't reach element or trigger event or change.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not using Enzyme (using React Testing Library for most of those functions). Here is my config that works out the box but it is not so different.

Defined in package.json not jest.config.js

```
  "jest": {
    "rootDir": "src",
    "globals": {
      "ts-jest": {
        "tsConfig": "tsconfig.test.json"
      }
    },
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "<rootDir>/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"
    ],
    "coverageDirectory": "jest-coverage",
    "setupFilesAfterEnv": [
      "@testing-library/react/cleanup-after-each",
      "jest-styled-components"
    ],
    "setupFiles": [
      "raf/polyfill",
      "<rootDir>/__jest__/browserMocks.js",
      "<rootDir>/__jest__/matchMediaMock.js"
    ],
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.tsx?$": "ts-jest"
    },
    "testRegex": "(/__tests__/.*|(\\.|/)(test|spec))\\.tsx?$",
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "ts",
      "tsx",
      "js",
      "jsx",
      "json",
      "node"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|svg|css|less|scss)$": "<rootDir>/__jest__/fileMock.js"
    }
  },
```